# have xdebug skip certain functions when debugging

Tags: php, debugging, zend-framework, xdebug

so basically I'm using Zend Framework's autoloader to autoload my functions. But because of this whenever I'm debugging, if I call any function xdebug would go to the autoload function before going to the actual function that is being called.

So if I call the function `func()`, it will first go to `autoload()` and then `func()` which increases debugging cost in terms of time, etc

Ideally if I call func(), it should go directly to func() while still using the autoloader.

Is there a way to specify xdebug (or using any PHP/Zend hack etc) to always skip a certain function (in this case my autoload function) when I'm debugging?

Comment: What do you mean by "goes to autoload function"? How does xdebug "go" there?

Comment: the debugger steps into the autoload function

Comment: Yes, because that's what your program does. It'll probably be more annoying to hide it and then have a bug in there. I don't quite see how this significantly increases "debugging costs"...

Comment: no this is more annoying. it's zend code so there is no bug. and this increases debugging cost because I have to keep on stepping through that function which I have no interest in debugging everytime I call whatever other function that I'm actually interested in debugging

Comment: I must be missing something.. But can't you put a breakpoint in the function you're interested in?

Comment: yes you are missing something...what is annoying is whenever I use the step into function...anyways do you or do you not have the answer?

Comment: Evidently it's no possible to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're single-stepping through your code, then you really should consider using breakpoints.  If you set a breakpoint at the start of the code block under investigation, then you can use the "run to breakpoint" option to skip over all the code that runs prior to the code under investigation.

If you set a breakpoint at the start of the constructor of the class you want to investigate, or the start of the method you want to investigate if you are sure the object instantization is okay, then you can skip through the autoloader.

Netbeans and Eclipse PDT both support setting breakpoints simply by clicking on the line number of the code you want to investigate.

Additionally, there's also the "step out" option in the debugger that lets you jump out of a function/method into which you have jumped using the "step in" option.  If you find yourself in the autoloader, just step out of it.

Comment: If you step out of a autoloader the typical result is that instead of being sent into the function you are sent after the function has finished.

Breakpoints can be useful, but they have one problem. If you wish to debug a function under only certain conditions then placing breakpoints into it will result it hitting even in cases where you don't care. So you would have to go continue a 10-30 times to get to the part you actually care about if it's a a function that runs a lot.

Conditional breakpoints might work, but aren't supported sadly.

Comment: It's true there's no conditional breakpoints in XDebug, but it's not hard to work around that.  Just do `if (condition) { do_some_kind_of_noop_here(); }` and put the breakpoint on the noop

Answer (score 7):

In eclipse with pdt in preferences: 
PHP -> Debug -> Step Filtering
click Add Filter, I added Autoloader.inc and no longer have to go through it

See [step_filtering_preferences](http://files.zend.com/help/PDT/step_filtering_preferences.htm) for more visual instructions

Comment: Works for PHPStorm as well, can't believe it's taken me so long to get this sorted. TY

Comment: Sadly, it does not seem to work on CLI and PHPUnit debugging.

Answer (score 5):

I know it's an old question, but I have arrived here from google.
In phpStorm you can ignore a specific function adding it to:

Preferences > PHP > Debug > Step Filters

with -> if it's a non-static method or :: if it's static

[image: phpstorm preferences]

Comment: In 2019.2.2 it's in Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Debug > Step Filters

Comment: Is there any way to have it also skip any function called from a skipped function? I tried this, but it still steps to the first `strtr()` call in the autoloader.